# How to keep track of distinct chars and words?

Tags: c++, while-loop, char, istream

Trying to write a function that analyzes an input file and outputs info such as distinct characters, the average length of each word, and the number of total words. I'm having trouble figuring out how to keep track of the distinct characters in a string. As an example the line:

To be   or not TO BE,       THAT IS       the question.

Should return 10 total words, 12 distinct characters, and 3.2 average word length.

This is the code I have so far:

```
void fileInfo(const string& fileName)
{
     ifstream in(fileName);
     if (in.fail())
     {
          cout << "Error, bad input file.";
     }

     string line = "";
     int wordTotal = 0;
     while (getline(in, line))
     {
          istringstream ss(line);
          string word = "";
          while (ss >> word)
          {
                wordTotal++;
                for (size_t i = 0, len = word.size(); i < len; i++)
                {
                    if (word.at(i))
                }
          }
     {






}
```

Comment: Since a `std::set` does not store duplicates, you can use a `std::set<char>` and insert each character from the word into the set.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a `std::unordered_set<char>` to store the letters of each word.  Since an `unordered_set` does not store duplicates, you end up with a set of distinct letters.

Second, you only want to count alphabetic characters, not punctuation or digits before plading in a set.  Thus you need to filter each character to ensure it is alphabetic.

```
void fileInfo(const string& fileName)
{
   std::unordered_set<char> cSet;
   //...
   while (ss >> word)
   {
       wordTotal++;
       for (auto v : word)
       {
           if (std::isalpha(v))
              cSet.insert(std::tolower(v));
       }
   }    
   //...
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac8b2d9f9be836f1)

The word is only inserted into the set if it is alphabetic.  Also note that the letter inserted is the lower case version.